# Excel File getting Corrupted when Downloading from S3

Tags: excel, angular, spring-boot, amazon-s3

**Objective:** To download file from S3 bucket on the UI (Angular)

**Service**

```
public byte[] downloadFileFromS3(String dfileName) {
        byte[] buffer = "Empty".getBytes();
        try {
            S3Object s3object = conn.getObject(bucketName, dfileName);
            S3ObjectInputStream inputStream = s3object.getObjectContent();
            buffer = new byte[(int) s3object.getObjectMetadata().getContentLength()];
            while (inputStream.read(buffer) > 0) {
                inputStream.read();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Exception occurred when accessing {} from S3 {}", dfileName, e.getMessage());
        }
        return buffer;
    }
```

***Controller***

```
@GetMapping("/download")
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> getFilefromS3(@RequestParam(name = "fileName") String fileName) {
        byte[] file = awsStorageHelper.downloadFileFromS3(fileName);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().header("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"")
                .body(new ByteArrayResource(file));
    }
```

**Implementation:** The spring application is deployed on EC2 instance which is having access to S3. The application will read the required file and pass the byte array to the angular application.
**Issue:** When downloading files like .docx or .txt the files get downloaded as expected but if .xlsx or .xls files are downloaded the files get corrupted. In case of zipping the file, when the contents of the .zip file are .docx or .txt the .zip file downloads without issue but if the .zip file contains .xlsx or .xls files the .zip file also gets corrupted.
*What exactly is going wrong here and is there a better way to download files form S3?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:** No need to convert the 'Input Stream' to 'Byte Array as Resource' in controller.
Pass same 'Input Stream' received from S3 service method and in controller pass as 'Input Stream as Resource'.
**Service:**

```
public InputStream downloadFileFromS3(String dfileName) {
        LOG.info("Downloading File {} ", dfileName);
        try {
            S3Object s3object = conn.getObject(bucketName, dfileName);
            return s3object.getObjectContent();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AeCoreException("Exception Occured Accessing File " + dfileName,
                    HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
@GetMapping("/download")
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getFilefromS3(@RequestParam(name = "fileName") String fileName) {
        InputStream file = awsStorageHelper.downloadFileFromS3(fileName);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"")
                .body(new InputStreamResource(file));
    }
```